# How to find the matrix $G$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, stochastic-differential-equations

I am currently studying how to transform ODEs to SDEs and stumbled upon the paper "Construction of Equivalent Stochastic Differential Equations. In the paper, there is an example using the second modeling procedure of transforming ODEs to SDEs.

Given that $V = GG^{T}$, where $V$ is a known $3 \times 3$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and $G$ is $3 \times 4$.

I have read about Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) where $A = U\Sigma V^{T}$, and tried to factor $G$ as $G = P \Sigma Q^{T}$, where $P$ is the eigenvectors of $GG^{T}$ and $\Sigma$ is the eigenvalues. However, $Q^{T}$ is still unknown (is it?).

I also read about Cholesky decomposition, where $A = LL^{T}$, and tried to factor $V$ as $V = GG^{T}$. Yes, I can get G but G is $3 \times 3$. I need a G that is $3 \times 4$.

What am I missing? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Dave What you're looking for is [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the suggestion. I will try to add more context to the question.

Comment: In general there are infinitely many such $G$.  For example, if $V$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, $G$ could be any $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @RoberIsrael For example, if $G$ is a $3 \times 4$ matrix and $V$ is $ 3 \times 3$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is there a way to get a $G$ that is $3 \times 4$ given that $V$ is $3 \times 3$? So far, using $A = LL^{T}$, I can get a $G$ but its $3 \times 3$.

Comment: If you have a $3\times 3$ $G$ that works, then append a column of zeros to get a $3 \times 4$ matrix that works.